# How to add a border to a ScrollView maintaining a image as background?

Tags: android, background, scrollview, border

I want to add a border to a ScrollView, but I also want to have a image as background.

By now, I'm using GradienDrawable() to set the ScrollView's border, but, I don't know what should I do to set a image as background too, without overwritting the image.

Here's part of my code:

```
public class Statistics extends ScrollView
```

{

```
public Statistics(int displayMode,Context context,int W, int H) {
    super(context);

    GradientDrawable borde =  new GradientDrawable();

    borde.setColors(new int[]{0x1F22FF22,0xAA22FF22,0x1F22FF22});
    borde.setGradientType(borde.LINEAR_GRADIENT);
    borde.setColor(0x1F22FF22);
    borde.setCornerRadius(10);
    borde.setStroke(5, 0xF000BE96);

    setBackground(borde);
    setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fondo2);
    setPadding(5,5,5,5);

    if(displayMode == LinearLayout.VERTICAL)
    {
        setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (int) (H * 0.25)));
    }
    else
    {
        setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams((int)(W*0.25),H));
    }

}
```

}

Can someone help me with it?
Or can suggest another way to do it?

Beforehand, thank you very much.

Comment: have you tried to set the border for the image that you want as the background?

Comment: Excuse me, do you mean, from an editor or programmatically? Because I don't know how to do that programmatically, and it is the way I want to do it, if it is possible.

Comment: I also tried to set a border to the image programmatically, but the image appears at the half of the view, and overlaps the border by its sides.
A kind of sandwich, where the image is the ham. :P

Comment: That can be useful, I'm trying.
Thanks.